# BeautifulSoup findAll() not showing every tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape every image at 9gag.com/hot page for educational purposes, I am learning python and webscraping.
Here is my code in very basic format:

```
import requests, os, bs4

url = 'https://9gag.com/hot'            
os.makedirs('9gag', exist_ok=True)   

print('Downloading page %s...' % url)

res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
find = soup.findAll("img")

print(find)
```

And here is html file on which I am working on:

[image: printscreen]

And I have a problem with understanding how exactly findAll() or other soup method works, because when I ran this code, there is no  tags found, although there are many of them. I don't know exactly how should I find something: through the  tag, through the tag and the class of it, by the parent or how?

Comment: Does it work if you search for a different tag, like `div` or `a`?

Comment: Put `assert '<img' in res.text` after `res.raise_for_status()` to see if you're getting the HTML you're expecting

Comment: Also try adding `user-agent` header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't seeing any `<img>` tags because the page loads the content dynamically, through AJAX. If you open developer tools in Firefox or Chrome, you will see that the main content is loaded through JSON from different url:

```
import requests, json

url = 'https://9gag.com/v1/featured-posts'

print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
data = res.json()
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
Downloading page https://9gag.com/v1/featured-posts...
{
    "meta": {
        "timestamp": 1562836411,
        "status": "Success",
        "sid": "9gVQ01EVjlHTUVkMMRVT1wEVFVTTn1TY"
    },
    "data": {
        "items": [
            {
                "itemId": "27568",
                "title": "The Corgi Who Plays Cheddar On Brooklyn Nine-Nine Has Passed Away",
                "url": "https://9gag.com/gag/adLm8rZ",
                "imageURL": "https://miscmedia-9gag-fun.9cache.com/images/featured/1562834921.0526_hYra9u_300.jpg",
                "upVoteCount": 19,
                "commentsCount": 12
            },
            {
                "itemId": "27566",
                "title": "Star Wars Reveals First Look At Sith Trooper For 'The Rise Of Skywalker'",
                "url": "https://9gag.com/gag/aZLGyEW",
                "imageURL": "https://miscmedia-9gag-fun.9cache.com/images/featured/1562833129.2422_NUTeny_300.jpg",
                "upVoteCount": 21,
                "commentsCount": 26
            },

... and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. New day - new knowledge to obtain. Would you be so kind and explain me as I am just starting - how it exacly works? In Chrome developers tools I can see that the image is, how to say it, "hardcoded" in html, where should I look for hint that it is JSON. And second question, the URL is some kind of 9gag API?

Comment: @KidOmega You should observe all network requests the page does (especially XHR requests). One of these requests contained the data in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, content is loaded dynamically.
You can use [requests_html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) that supports javascript instead of requests.

```
import requests, os, bs4
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://9gag.com/hot'            
os.makedirs('9gag', exist_ok=True)   

print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()

find = r.html.find("img")

print(find)
```

It gives you something like that :

```
[<Element 'img' alt='Avatar' id='jsid-avatar' src=''>, <Element 'img' loading='lazy' src='https://miscmedia-9gag-fun.9cache.com/images/thumbnail-facebook/1557283905.6809_vudeXy_100x100.jpg'>, <Element 'img' loading='lazy' src='https://miscmedia-9gag-fun.9cache.com/images/thumbnail-facebook/1557376304.186_U5U7u5_100x100.jpg'>,..]
```